# Error in sqlException when attempting to use generated named query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I have created a bean:

```
package beans;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import mazeJPA.Forumcategory;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class ForumBean
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ForumBean
{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mazeEJB")
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public ForumBean(){}


    public List<Forumcategory> getCategories()
    {
        return em.createNamedQuery
        (
                "Forumcategory.findAll", Forumcategory.class
        ).getResultList();
    }
}
```

and its entity class

```
package mazeJPA;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the forumcategory database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="forumcategory")
@NamedQuery(name="Forumcategory.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM Forumcategory f")
public class Forumcategory implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int cid;

    private String desc;

    private String name;

    public Forumcategory() {
    }

    public int getCid() {
        return this.cid;
    }

    public void setCid(int cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I call getCategories() from my servlet I get an sql exception:

```
 Internal Exception:
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
 error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
 MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC, NAME FROM
 forumcategory' at line 1 Error Code: 1064 Call: SELECT CID, DESC, NAME
 FROM forumcategory Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Forumcategory.findAll"
 referenceClass=Forumcategory sql="SELECT CID, DESC, NAME FROM
 forumcategory")
```

My table is:

```
  cid INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, desc TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cid)
```

I don't know why this is happening. Have I got something wrong with the mapping? I have only recently added this to my project is that anything to do with it i.e. do I have to generate all the tables at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DESC` is a **[reserved](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html) sql word**, so you have to scape it, using `desc`, for example

```
SELECT CID, `DESC`, NAME FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you I should have realised that.

Comment: You are welcome, sometimes this things happens ;). I would avoid to use this name for the column is possible.

Comment: I changed it to description which I should have used in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

DESC is a reserved keyword in most SQL. Seems that your JPA provider doesn't automatically escape these for you (surround in quotes). Some JPA implementations (e.g DataNucleus JPA) do that for you.